# JQuery chained arrays of promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I created a JQuery function called "getScript" which I can use to download a script dynamically; this function returns a Promise which is resolved when the given script URL is downloaded, and works OK.

I am now in a context where some scripts must be loaded in a specific order; so I created three arrays of Promises generated by "getScript" (called a1, a2 and a3 below), and I tryed something like this:

```js
  function getAllScripts((a1, a2, a3) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.when.apply(a1).then(() => {
        return $.when.apply(a2).then(() => {
          return $.when.apply(a3).then(() => {
            // do something...
            resolve(result);
          }, reject);
        }, reject);
      }, reject);
    });
  });
```

The problem with this code is that after the first iteration over "a1" array, all promises are already resolved! So my scripts are not loaded in the good order at all...

I've tried to use ".done()" instead of ".then()", but the result is the same.

Any idea?

Best regards,

Thierry

Comment: I think that the issue you have is that you use apply wrong. The apply method accept context (what's inside this) as first argument and array is the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You're using apply in wrong way, try this:

```js
  function getAllScripts((a1, a2, a3) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.when.apply($, a1).then(() => {
        return $.when.apply($, a2).then(() => {
          return $.when.apply($, a3).then(() => {
            // do something...
            resolve(result);
          }, reject);
        }, reject);
      }, reject);
    });
  });
```

Apply have two arguments first is context and second is array, in this case the context can be $ or just null it should no matter (unless the when jQuery function use this).

Comment: Oops! Sorry for this mistake in my code sample but the "$" was given correctly as first argument to "$.when.apply()"...

Comment: I actually managed to handle this use case by only setting the scripts URLs into the different arrays, and by calling "$.when.apply($, a1.map(getScript)).then(...)". But I still don't understand why all the promises are resolved immediately with the initial behaviour described in this topic...  :(

Comment: @tflorac maybe you have fast internet try to throttle in Dev tools or use fake getScript that use setTimeout and longer delay to debug it.